# GCP Cloud Function: Cannot find npm module

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

so i am building a cloud function, and I structured my code into multiple files.

My index.js goes as this:

```
const { postHandler } = require('./requestHandler.js');

const httpHandler = (req, res) => {
  const { method } = req;

  switch (method) {
    case 'POST':
      postHandler(req, res);
      break;
    case 'GET':
      getHandler(req, res);
      break;
    case 'DELETE':
      deleteHandler(req, res);
      break;
    case 'PUT':
      putHandler(req, res);
      break;
    default:
      return res.sendStatus(400).json({message: 'Invalid method. Allowed are POST, GET, DELETE'});
  }
}

exports.httpHandler = httpHandler
```

And this is the requestHandler

```
const createReviewApp = require('./createReviewApp')

const postHandler = ( req, res ) => {
  const { path } = req;
  return createReviewApp( req, res )
}

module.exports = { postHandler }
```

This is the createReviewApp

```
const _compute = require('./computeClass.js');
const _dns = require('./dnsClass.js');
const _storage = require('./storageClass.js');

const createReviewApp = ( req, res ) => {
     // doing something
}
```

And this is my computeClass

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute')

const projectId = process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID;

class ComputeSingleton {
  constructor(){
    this.compute = new Compute({
      projectId,
    });
  }
  getVm({zoneName, vmName}){
    return this.getZone({zoneName}).vm(vmName).get();
  }
  getZone({zoneName}){
    return this.compute.zone(zoneName);
  }
  createVm({zoneName, vmName, config}){
    return this.getZone({zoneName}).createVM(vmName, config);
  }
  deleteVm({zoneName, vmName}){
    return this.getZone({zoneName}).vm(vmName).delete();
  }
}

module.exports = new ComputeSingleton()
```

Now, in my computeClass i am getting the following error:

```
 Cannot find module '@google-cloud/compute
```

I have my dependencies installed, do I need to put all my code in one file?

**Edit:** I am testing it on functions nodejs emulator

Comment: Yes you have to pull all dependencies

Comment: I am testing it on functions nodejs emulator.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need to have your code in one file.  It sounds like you just don't actually have `@google-cloud/compute` in your functions project package.json and fully installed.